# How to open Bootstrap 4 modal on first click instead of second click using Vue.js

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I currently have the below component, what I'm trying to do is I want to load the data from the api into my modal. The data is loading as expected, however the modal only opens on the second click. The first click is not opening the modal. However when the modal opens and then I close it. It all opens again. But when I refresh it does not open.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <tbody v-for="(value, key) in users" :key="key.id">
            <tr>
                <td>{{ value.type }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr v-for="user in value.user" :key="user.id">
                <td class='text-center'>
                    <button class="btn btn-default" @click="edit(user.id)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEdit">
                        <i class="far fa-edit"></i> Edit
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

        <edit-modal
            v-if="showEdit"
            :info="info"/>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import EditModal from './EditModal.vue';

    export default {
        components: {
            EditModal
        },
        data() {
            return {
                showEdit: false,
                users: [],
                info: {
                    name: '',
                    status: '',
                }
            }
        },
        methods: {
            edit(userId) {

                axios.get(`user/${userId}`)
                    .then(response => {
                        this.info = response.data
                        this.showEdit = true
                    }).catch(error => {
                        console.log(error)
                    })

            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="modal fade" id="modalEdit">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
                <div class="modal-content">

                    <div class="modal-header bg-primary">
                        <h6 class="modal-title text-white font-weight-bold">Edit</h6>
                        <div class="cursor-pointer" data-dismiss="modal" title="Close">
                            <i class="fas fa-times text-white"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-sm-4">User</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">{{ info.name }}</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
        props: {
            info: {
                type: Object,
                default: () => ({
                    name: '',
                    status: '',
                })
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

The weird thing is that if I remove the axios request in the edit method

```
methods: {
            edit(userId) {
               this.showEdit = true
            }
        }
```

The modal opens from the first click. But I need the axios request to populate the data in the modal.

Comment: Same issue here. Did you get a resolution?

Comment: @JonL yes, all what was happening is that the button should have a fixed height between the text inputs. Need to add a height between the button and assign a fixed height so the button would not change position when clicking it.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to write `return true` here instead

```
methods: {
            edit(userId) {

                axios.get(`user/${userId}`)
                    .then(response => {
                        this.info = response.data
                        this.showEdit = true
                    }).catch(error => {
                        console.log(error)
                    })

            }
        }
```

this should work.

Answer (score 0):

The first click probably doesn't work because if you use v-if the component doesn't exists in the dom until the condition is truthy. In this case, the button data-target and data-toggle will not exist until this.showEdit is true.

The first time you click the button this.showEdit is false until you get the response and the second time you click the button this.showEdit is true because you already got a response earlier but the data are probably outdated until you get the second response.

The solution i would use is to set showEdit true on click and then just pass the userId to your modal as a prop and fetch the data on ready/mounted hook of the modal component and then fill your info.

And by the way, i think your button data-target and your modal id should match.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried with "v-show" instead

```
<edit-modal
        v-show="showEdit"
        :info="info"/>
```

Comment: that's weird... obviously your "edit-modal" component on the "created life hook" should run some code to show it " $("#modalEdit").modal("show");"

Comment: I want to avoid using jquery

Comment: I want to avoid jQuery syntax

Comment: there you go then: https://codepen.io/kimpetersend1/pen/LajgaW or this one https://vuejs.org/v2/examples/modal.html